# C# RijndaelManaged to Python equivalent

Tags: c#, python, aes, rijndael

I have the following C# code (code is inherited and can't compile it). This is used to decrypt and unzip a saved file.

```
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Text;
using ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.Zip;

//Not the real key but same amount of chars
private const string kEncyptionKey = "01234567";

public string DecryptAndDecompressText (string strFileName)
{
    // Decryption ///
    FileStream fin = null;
    try
    {
        fin = new FileStream(strFileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
    }
    catch (System.IO.FileNotFoundException)
    {
        return "";
    }

    MemoryStream    memoryToDecompress =  new MemoryStream();

    UnicodeEncoding UE       = new UnicodeEncoding();
    RijndaelManaged RMCrypto = new RijndaelManaged();

    // This is the encryption key for our file 
    byte[] key = UE.GetBytes(kEncyptionKey);

    // Decrypt the data to a stream
    CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream( memoryToDecompress, 
                                        RMCrypto.CreateDecryptor(key, key),
                                        CryptoStreamMode.Write);
    byte [] fileBuffer = new byte[fin.Length];
    fin.Read(fileBuffer, 0, fileBuffer.Length);
    cs.Write(fileBuffer, 0, fileBuffer.Length);

    fin.Close();

    // Reset the index of the Memory Stream
    memoryToDecompress.Position = 0;

    // Let the GC clean this up, we still need the memory stream
    //cs.Close();   


    // Decompress the File
    ZipInputStream s;
    s = new ZipInputStream(memoryToDecompress);

    ZipEntry theEntry;
    try
    {
        theEntry = s.GetNextEntry();
    }
    catch (System.Exception)
    {
        // Could not open the file...
        return "";
    }
}
```

I'm trying to create a python program to do the same. This is what I've got:

```
from Crypto.Cipher import AES

KEY = '01234567'.encode('utf-16be')

_f = open('<file>', 'r')

 _content = _f.read()

_cipher = AES.new(KEY, AES.MODE_CBC, KEY)

_dcontent = _cipher.decrypt(_content)

with open('extract.zip', 'w') as newfile:
    newfile.write(_dcontent)

_f.close()
```

I'm writing the result to the disk since I expect it to be a zip file (which contains one file). However I can't open the file with Archive Manager.

Any suggestions are welcome!

Answer (score 2):

You have to use the **same key**. `System.Text.UnicodeEncoding` is the UTF-16le encoding which also has an equivalent in python:

```
KEY = '01234567'.encode('utf-16le')
```

You have to read and write the files in **binary mode** if you're on Windows:

```
_f = open('<file>', 'rb')
...
open('extract.zip', 'wb')
```

Comment: Can you be more specific? Do you get any errors? If not, is the output file written? If so, is the output file same size as the expected output file? If so, is the expected file the same as the output file except for the first 16 bytes?

Comment: I don't get any errors. A file is written. The input and output files are of the same size. The first 32 bytes of each are different.  `0e50 74aa 793e 0f10 967d 679e df3e ba8e 97c3 6092 4aa4 d45e 366c 437e 8abe c13d` vs `4b50 0403 0014 0000 0008 b67b 40be 4d05 bb83 ae92 0000 2331 0005 0008 0000 50531` (obtained using hexdump)

Comment: If the first 16 bytes are different from what you would expect, then the issue would have been a wrong IV, but since this is 32 bytes, I really have no idea what it could be. Also, I'm not sure what *"input"* in *"input and output files"* is supposed to be.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the [proper zip file library](https://docs.python.org/2/library/zipfile.html). I am guessing that is something format specific that is failing on your write statement. Using this library should avoid such drawbacks. The `open` function can take a password as optional in case it is protected.